# Ansible - generate .rst file from module's DOCUMENTATION string

Tags: python, ansible, documentation, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have written custom Ansible module and documented it using standard Ansible convention, *i.e.* by writing `DOCUMENTATION` and `EXAMPLES` global strings in module file.

I already have some of the documentation generated using `Sphinx 1.8.3` and hosted locally. I would like to have Ansible documenation included in Sphinx generated pages. My directory structure is fairly simple:

```
./ansible/docs
├── conf.py
├── index.rst
├── _static
└── _templates
./ansible/library/
├── __init__.py
└── module.py
```

Now, I could write documentation as function docstrings and then include it using Sphinx `.. automodule::` directive. This works, but uses different format than Ansible `DOCUMENTATION` string.

Although [Ansible module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/dev_guide/developing_modules_documenting.html) goes on in depth, how the docstrings should be formatted, it does not seem to provide any information how to generate docs locally.

What is the correct way to convert Ansible module documentation to `.rst` file, so that it could be included by `Sphinx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [the provided Makefile](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.7.5/docs/docsite/Makefile#L36) in the `docs/docsite` directory (you can also run [`make webdocs`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.7.5/Makefile#L383) from the top-level). You'll want to ensure you have loaded [the docsite requirements](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.7.5/docsite_requirements.txt) into your virtualenv, in addition to `pip install -e $PWD` or its equivalent because the docsite sphinx uses some of ansible's own libraries to do its work.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work. I found using plugin formatter script directly easier, such as `cd /data/github/ansible/docs/` and then `bin/plugin_formatter.py  -t rst  --template-dir=templates -o rst --module-dir=${custom_module_path}`. Unfortunately, it looks like [Ansible default templates](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/docs/templates/plugin.rst.j2) use quite a lot of embedded HTML, which is not looking very good, when I try to use it with standard Sphinx themes (such as Alabaster). All in all it is a bit hacky solution - seems like there is no proper way to do it outside Anisble.

Comment: @mdaniel, can you tell me where the custom module (.py file) needs to be copied in order to generate the rst file ? I tried to copy mymodule.py (my custom module file) to 'lib/ansible/modules/$CATEGORY/' as mentioned in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/dev_guide/developing_modules_documenting.html but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, can you please help me out here ?